# why opengl shader mix function for two transparent png photo become black?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, glsles

Photo 1 is:

[image]

Photo 2 is:

[image]

Of course photo 2 is partly transparent.

But when i mix them in shader such as that:

```
vec4 add(vec4 one, vec4 two){
   return mix(one, two, two.a);
}
```

They become partly black like the following:

[image]

i'm so confused about why it will generate black color.
I know mix function basely implements like these:

```
A*(1-alpha)+B*alpha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i solve this problem by dividing rgb by alpha

```
two.rgb / two.a
```

thought i don't know why. but i remove the black color successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The black color doesn't generate, it is the color of your background. It shows up because you are mixing the two colors and their alphas. You can see the black backround when the resulting alpha is less than one.

You should only mix the `RGB` color values based on the alpha of your second image like this:

```
vec4 add(vec4 one, vec4 two){
   return mix(one.rgb, two.rgb, two.a);
}
```

Comment: sorry for delay reply,but  apply these changes still not work.

Comment: And are you sure you set your gl_FragColor's alpha to always 1.0? `gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);`

Comment: yeah,i think it is the texture's problem. thought i don't know why it has to make my texture gray where it's white with alpha originally.